# Express.js middleware extra (fourth) argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

On the **optional arguments to an Express.js middleware** , probably a fourth one apart from being an error handling middleware, I have a use case where it comes useful. It may be achieved by a different way, but anyways.

I want to make some api routes permission checked, the middleware I wish to write should look up database for a requesting user for how many reputation points (integer) he/she has. I defined an object to hold privileges and reputation points required as key value pairs. Later, middleware should look up this privileges object to see if the user has greater than or equal reputation points for a **corresponding action**. I want to pass this **corresponding action** name which is a key in the privileges object as a different string for each route. This can be achieved by sending the string `actionName`s via requests to the routes, but I find it less secure (data in request can be tampered to have an action name that a malicious user has access to and to have required data fields for another wished but not permitted action).

All the case is just like that of SE's.

By the way, apparently I also need route based (not Router based) middleware mounting, I am not sure if Express.js supports, but this is another story.

Maybe one can describe and ask this use case as **can I parametrize a middleware function with my parameters, not just by incoming req and res objects?**

How can I achieve this use case with Express.js middleware? Or should I use another mechanism?

```
/// Privilege Check middleware
// used per route with corresponding actionName
// signature function (request, response, next, actionNameOneOfKeysInPrevilegesObject::String)
var privilegeCheck = function (req, res, next, actionName) {
    db.one(
        `
            SELECT reputation FROM users WHERE id = $(id)
        `,
        {id: req.user.id} // remember req.user was set by jwt.sign(data) during login or signup with demanded data; here it is {id:, name:, username:,}
    )
        .then(function (data) {
            if(data >= privileges[actionName]) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                res.status(403).json({errorMessage: "You need to have " + privileges.questionUpvote + " reputation to upvote."});
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
};

// reputations needed for privileged actions
var privileges =
{
    questionAsk: 5,
    answer: 15,
    acceptAnswer: 0,
    comment: 5,
    questionEdit: 20,
    answerEdit: 20,
    commentsEdit: 0,
    postsUpvote: 30,
    postsDownvote: 30,
    commentsUpvote: 5,
    questionUpvote: 10,
    questionDownvote: 125,
}
```

Comment: According to the linked shared in answer of @William Express.js supports route-based middleware; a side question mark in my above question has been clarified.

Answer (score 5):

Use route-specific middleware like so:

```
function privilegeCheck(actionName) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        db.one(
            `
                SELECT reputation FROM users WHERE id = $(id)
            `,
            {id: req.user.id} // remember req.user was set by jwt.sign(data) during login or signup with demanded data; here it is {id:, name:, username:,}
        )
            .then(function (data) {
                if(data >= privileges[actionName]) {
                    next();
                }
                else {
                    res.status(403).json({errorMessage: "You need to have " + privileges.questionUpvote + " reputation to upvote."});
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
        ;
    }
};

// Then, for each of your routes, invoke your privilegeCheck() function
// as an "in-between" argument between your path and your route handler 
// function.

app.get('/my/route', privilegeCheck("myActionName"), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('handled /my/route');
});
```

See the "Application-level middleware" section at http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html, starting from "This example shows a middleware sub-stack that handles GET requests to the /user/:id path." 
But the documentation there does not show that you can chain functions in the app.get(). You can see that at

https://scotch.io/tutorials/route-middleware-to-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-node-js

In fact, you can have as many "middleware" (ie three-argument function) arguments to any of Express's route handling functions (get(), put(), post(), delete()) as you need.

Comment: Waow, thank you, and function returns function was the key, I knew it!

Comment: What I and you @William mean by router-level differs. I thought it was meant the middleware that applies to all routes in a single router. Anyways the way you use it in above code is what I need and mean by route-based middleware, though this name not in express docs, I made it up.

Comment: I think "route level" would be a better term, but "router-level" is the term in the docs.

Comment: Wait, no it is not router-level. My bad. One second.

Comment: By the way, does two subsequent examples in the docs mentioned runs only for the path written there: `router.use('/user/:id', ...`, `router.get('/user/:id', ...` ? apart form being for all and for only GET HTTP requests.

Comment: If you use .use() then your middleware runs for all HTTP methods. If you use .get() it runs for just GET HTTP method. There is of course .put() .post() .delete() etc.

Comment: And also the usage of `next('route')` to pass to the next route url is explained very insufficently. I think `next('route')` makes Express skip the [middleware] functions in the current router url to the next url defined in the router. It seems to be a special call for `next` with a special argument; `'route'`. Also the thing they call as a `route` in the comments is ambiguous. `var router = express.Router()`, this is a router. but this is a route `router.use('a-route-url', aRouteFunctionAndORMiddleWare(){...`.

Comment: Express considers a 3 arg function to be middleware and a 2 arg function to be a route handler (ie terminating middleware). Fun fact, you can include as many middleware arguments as you need.

Comment: Express says it takes it as an error handling Middleware when argument number is four which is the obstacle for me to do what I wish to do.

Comment: Is returning a new function with each request made writing inefficient code?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about overhead due to the extra function. Technically, the overhead of the extra function call occurs once per route when your application boots. After that, it is exactly the same performance characteristics as not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Express is coded so that if your middleware function has exactly four parameters, it is considered error handling middleware. IMO this was not a good design decision.

To do what you want to do, the canonical way to do is to attach data to the request stream (req).

For example:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.data = {foo:'bar'};

});


app.use(function(req,res,next){
  const data = req.data;
}):
```

Coming from languages like Java, I thought this was some of the craziest coding ever, but it works because req is unique to that request + JS is "single-threaded".

Comment: In any languages, if it was a http request it ought to be unique without any thread feature of the lang complier/interpreter. However the problem is I do not want to write a seperate function for each case (ie. for each route). I want to program it one more level up, abstracting the function that does what I want with the argument I give it for each route.